# How can I add csproj files to Team Explorer?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I have a complex solution with 42 projects.
Every time I add new files, the csproj files change.
These files are not visible as part of the solution in VS, so I can't commit from VS.
When I try to add these files (Add, existing file - xxx.csproj - *.*), VS answers "Can't open file. The file is open as project or solution".
This is right, the file is open, but how can I add this file to be able to commit?

Answer (score 0):

If the `csproj` file is changing, then it will be shown in the changes in the team explorer. May be there is an entry of `*.csProj` in your `.gitignore` file. Please check the `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding the .csproj to the **solution**, but it should be ***Team Explorer*'s *Changes*** window.

When you add a new file and save the project (e.g. via Visual Studio -> File -> Save All) then the `csproj` file should appear in *Team Explorer*'s **Changes** window.

[image]

Please note `csproj` files are not directly visible in the *Solution Explorer* window - they are shown as project (not as files).